# う◯こ versus う◯ち - which is more childish?

Tags: word-choice, child-speech

I was watching last week's ホンマでっか, and there one of the learned panel talked about うんこ (or う◯こ as it was subtitled), and Matsuko Deluxe on the celeb panel hectored him with a "Use うんち at least as it's not so childish!" (I could very well have these two back-to-front)

So, the question is which is less childish? WWWJDIC list both as children's language.

For a bonus point, why do even late-night shows use う◯こ and う◯ち in subtitles?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what Matsuko actually said, but I would say both words are almost the same in terms of childishness. To me うんこ sounds more explicit and vulgar, while うんち is a bit more euphemistic, milder or cuter. So "careful adults should use うんち in variety shows" is an understandable statement (especially when it was a women who firstly said it).

That said, vulgar and direct words are more likely to get a laugh. I think I actually hear うんこ more often on TV variety shows. Male comedians on TV almost always use うんこ.

In scientific or serious settings both words are inappropriate, and you should use 大便/便 (for humans), 糞 (for animals/insects) or 排泄物.

As for why they were "censored", please [read this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11810/5010). Simply, う○こ would look more funny by emphasizing its dirtiness.