# Lolita Complex changed to be ロリヰタコンプレックス in Zetsuen no Tempest?

Tags: words, slang, anime, internet-slang

In Zetsuen no Tempest, a bunch of guys were guessing to reasons why someone (Yoshino) might hide his girlfriend, and writing them on a whiteboard. One of the reasons that came up was that his gf might be an elementary schooler. When this was written (see attached pic), it was written as "ロリヰタコンプレックス". Obviously, the black sheep here is "ヰ" (katakana for the archaic "wi" if I'm not mistaken). I'm wondering if this was just a really silly one-off way of censoring "ロリタコンプレックス", or if this is referring to something more standard? For example, ヲタク being a "less normie" way of writing オタク.
[image: Zetsuen No Tempest Screenshot]

Comment: For that matter, I wonder if the ヲタく spelling hearkens back to 男【を】 to emphasize that many (most?) _otaku_ types are male?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi No, お in おたく is etymologically 御, the honorific prefix. It has nothing to do with 男. I don't think there is a profound reason to use ヲ instead of オ.

Comment: @naruto, ya, historically I’m aware that the initial お is the honorific prefix 御. I’m wondering if the modern slangy spelling with initial ヲ might be an intentional allusion to older 男【を】. From your perspective, it sounds like maybe not?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Not "maybe not" but "absolutely not". オタク might mainly referred to males in mass media in the 1980s, but when people started to use ヲ in 2000s, it was already completely gender-neutral. Most ジャニヲタ are female.

Comment: @naruto, very helpful context, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen ロリータ written this way anywhere else, so I agree that this is just "a silly one-off way of censoring ロリータ". Of course this is a [fake "censoring" for humorous effect](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/11833/5010).

Looks like there are a few existing works whose title contain the spelling ロリヰタ, but they are not well-known. (If there is this kind of odd spelling in a book title, it is not censorship but simply to make it eye-catching.)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure Lolita is supposed to be written ロリータ, and that character should be substitute for an elongation mark, as to why "wi" is used for "i", it might be the same reason why を is often merged with "お" sound, but I'm not entirely sure.
Quick googling gave me a novel by Takemoto Novala titled "Lolita" that was spelled exactly like that, so what it might be is just some quaint/clever way to write it using the archaic character, and teenagers do like stand out by adopting unconventional methods in various things. So your "less normie way" guess shouldn't be far from the truth.